# haproxy missing fetch method in ACL expression

Tags: haproxy

i am using these conditions in ha proxy

```
use_backend test if { path_beg -i /test/ } { { ssl_fc_has_crt } || { src 10.0.0.25 }  || { src 10.1.0.152 }  || { src 10.0.2.41 }  || { src 10.0.0.158}  || { src 64.32.12.252 }  || { src 35.43.19.101 } || { src 80.240.254.1 } || { src 82.10.80.7 } }
```

But i am seeing this error:

```
error detected while parsing switching rule : missing fetch method in ACL expression '{'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs show `{ }` like it could group ACLs, but doesn't elaborate on it:

```
A condition is formed as a disjunctive form:

   [!]acl1 [!]acl2 ... [!]acln  { or [!]acl1 [!]acl2 ... [!]acln } ...
```

So maybe it isn't grouping at all. All examples with `{}` i can see are for anonymous ACLs.
You want to combine AND with OR in one condition and haproxy isn't very helpful, but here is something that should work:

```
acl allowed_to_test_site src 10.0.0.25 10.0.0.24 10.1.0.152 10.0.2.41 10.0.0.158 64.32.12.252 35.43.19.101 80.240.254.1 82.10.80.7
acl allowed_to_test_site ssl_fc_has_crt
use_backend backend-sonar if { path_beg -i /test/ } allowed_to_test_site
```

Few points to explain here:

1. src IP1 || src IP2 can be declared as `acl ip src IP1 IP2` and so on. such list works as multiple OR
2. declaring ACL multiple times works again as multiple OR
   [Docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#4.2-acl) say:

```
acl <aclname> <criterion> [flags] [operator] <value> ...
Declare or complete an access list.
```

which could use some more explicit explaination
3. AND is implicit

This way we get the logic of `(path_beg -i /test/) AND ( ssl_fc_has_crt OR src matches one of the IPs)`
Maybe one day haproxy will have better syntax for that.